# neo4j compare call graphs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to identify similar functionality by comparing call graphs in my code base releases

If foo invokes bar which logs before and after invoking baz the call graph will look like:

```
               bar-:INVOKES->logd
 foo-:INVOKES->bar-:INVOKES->baz
               bar-:INVOKES->logi
```

1. How do I create multiple graphs ? a graph for each release
2. Given the function signature as entry point and 2 releases, how do I compare paths ?

Comment: Please share input data structure and what have you tried.

Comment: please also give us an example and your expected result.